# How to kill all processes apart from specific one

Tags: command-line, process

On my local server, many java processes are running, and at the same time I am using Eclipse. Now when I need to restart my processes (I start processes through a shell script), before every start I need to kill the old processes through:

Method 1:-
`kill -9 $Pid`     (for each process one by one, which is time-consuming)

Method 2:- 
`killall -9 java` (for all processes - easy, but Eclipse will be killed too unnecessarily)

In the case of Method 2 Eclipse will also be killed, which I never want. Is there any way out of this? I bet there must be :P

Edit: I am using ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: are you using openjdk?

Comment: no it is **java-7-oracle**

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Give a try to this command:

```
ps ax | grep "java" | egrep -v "eclipse" | cut -b1-06 | xargs -t kill
```

this will search for all processes containing java and execluding eclipse then kill them

Comment: ++1 for *not* using `-9` indiscriminately. You should ever give a process the chance to exit gracefully.

Comment: `pgrep` is better than `ps | grep` as else you risk killing the grep statement itself.

Comment: @abligh The problem is with `pgrep` you are not able to distinguish which processes are running eclipse, because even `pgrep -l` will just report `java`. @ Maythux, just for reference, `egrep` is deprecated and should not be used, since `grep -E` does exactly the same, although you don't even need `grep -E` since you're matching a fixed string; so just `grep -v "eclipse"` (or if you want to be fancy `[...] | grep -F "java" | grep -vF "eclipse | [...]"`)

Comment: @kos: untested: `pkill '/java\(.*eclipse\)\@!'`

Comment: @abligh What's `\@!`? If that's a Perl-ism it's not going to work, because `pkill` only supports EREs, I've tried to reduce this whole task to a single command already using `pkill` with negative lookaheads and that failed for this reason.

Comment: @kos Match (with zero length) when the previous atom doesn't match.

Comment: @abligh: That's not in [`regex(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/regex.7.html), so it probably won't work.

Answer (score 12):

Using `awk`

```
ps ax | awk '/java/ && !/eclipse/ {system("kill "$1)}'
```

The command kills all `java` processes, but not the process `eclipse`.

Comment: More elegant (and faster) then the answer from @maythux IMHO...  **;-)**

Comment: I agree with Fabby, nice!

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
pgrep -af 'java' | grep -Po '^[^ ]+(?!.*eclipse)' | xargs kill
```

- `pgrep -af 'java'` searches for `java` in the full command line of the processes and list them
- `grep -Po '^[^ ]+(?!.*eclipse)'` looks among the searched processes and get the process IDs of the processes that do not have `eclipse` in their full command lines
- `xargs kill` will kill the processes.

Comment: +1 for a short and elegant solution.   Note that it would have been possible to have an even more efficient (only one command: `pkill`) solution if `pgrep/pkill` supported perl regex'es which you use in the 2nd step above.  Unfortunately `pgrep`/`pkill` only support extended-regexps (like `egrep/grep -E`).

Comment: @arielf You are absolutely right..it would have been most efficient if `pgrep`/`pkill` supports PCRE..

Answer (score 0):

`jps -m | grep -v eclipse | awk '{print $1}' | xargs -t kill`

Use jps to make sure that you are looking for just the java commands and not all the commands which have java in their path.

Answer (score 0):

```
ps ax | grep "java" | egrep -v "eclipse" | cut -b1-06 | xargs -t kill
```

Comment: It would have been nicer to explain the commands, rather that just give a cryptic command string. Also, what about my long-running command "orkjavagoob.sh"