# Shortcut key to kill all current processes

Tags: shortcut-keys, shutdown

I have a slow laptop with Ubuntu 18.04, and it hangs often while I have several Chrome tabs open alongside VS Code. This hangup takes nearly a dozen minutes to repair itself. Sometimes the "window is not responding" box will appear after a minute, but it would be unclickable, hence not useful.

Thus, I always find it faster to force shut down my laptop and re run the applications again. For the time being, I cannot upgrade my laptop. However, I do not want to degrade its life either, by forcing shut down once every two-three days.

I realized that I don't actually need to force shut down my laptop, I just need to kill the applications that are running at that moment. I am fine with losing unsaved work (it's very little as I keep saving my work very often). Thus, I wish to know the proper way to be able to kill Chrome and VS Code if my laptop ever hangs again.

I did look at the following thread: [How to kill all processes apart from specific one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/652139/how-to-kill-all-processes-apart-from-specific-one) and think that it might be possible to create a shell script to run something similar to the following command: `ps ax | grep -P "chrome|code" cut -b1-06 | xargs -t kill`. However, I am not sure if it is the best way to do so, and if it will even work, considering my PC is hung up, and might not be able to execute a shell script everytime.

Comment: Probably better trying to switch browser...

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have thought about it earlier, but I regularly require more than a dozen Chrome extensions that are currently not actively developed for Firefox. If they were available for Firefox, I would happily switch.